# Extracting element in Javascript from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to read from a json file that simply has the following in it:
[3000,2500,6000,2200,5000,1300]. It is saved as data.txt. In my code I create an empty array as the first step. I then pass a function to the $.getJSON function which reads the contents of the data.txt file. I then read every item in the JSON array and push it to the empty array I created earlier. When I try to print the first element of the array, arr[0], I get undefined. If I place the document.write(arr[0]); expression before the last bracket, it give me the correct answer,3000, but I need it to be outside. Why is this happening?

```
arr=[];

$.getJSON('data.txt',function(data) {

for (var i in data){  
arr.push(data[i]);  
}

}); 

document.write(arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getJSON`, just like any other AJAX request, is asynchronous. Anything that relies on the data it gets MUST be placed inside the success callback (or in a function called by said callback).

As a result, you won't be able to use `document.write()` because the document will have already loaded.

Instead, replace `arr.push(data[i])` with some code for adding `data[i]` to the document properly, such as by putting it in a text node and appending it to the body.

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET","data.txt",true);
x.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var r = window.JSON ? JSON.parse(this.responseText) : eval("("+this.responseText+")"),
      node, i;
    for( i in data) {
      node = document.createTextNode(data[i]);
      document.body.appendChild(node);
    }
  }
};
x.send();
```

Comment: So how would I then have an array that holds all the contents of the array in the json document then?

Comment: Oh, well in that case you'd want to keep the `arr.push()` line. Just remember that you can't use `arr` outside of the callback like you tried to in your question.

Comment: Is there any way to read from a JSON file in a non asynchronous way such that I can use the array later?

Comment: Yes, but it's a very bad idea.

Comment: That said, if you have PHP or another server-side language involved, you could just have it embed the JSON directly into your script. For PHP that'd be `var arr = <?php echo file_get_contents("data.txt"); ?>;`

Comment: It's called AJAX for a reason. The first A stands for "Asynchronous". Using Synchronous requests causes the browser to hang for as long as it takes to load the file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't iterate over an array with the `for...in` syntax. This is the syntax for iterating over the properties of an object, which isn't what you want.

   Just use a `for` loop:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

   }
   ```
2. AJAX is asynchronous, so `arr` is defined after `document.write()` is called. If you want to work with the value, do it from within the `getJSON` callback.